# Trotter-Kato Formula

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Recently I read the appendix of the book *Scaling Limits of Interacting Particle Systems* written by C.Kipnis and C.Landim. I am stuck at Page 323. It says: if $P_t$ is the transition matrix of a continuous time Markov chain and $L$ is the generator,
\begin{equation}
P_t=\mathrm{e}^{tL}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(I+\frac{t}{n}L\right)^n,\forall t\geqslant 0.
\end{equation}
I search it online and then find the paper T. Kato, *On the Trotter–Lie product formula*, Proc. Japan Acad. 50 (1974) 694–698. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy/volume-50/issue-9/On-the-Trotter-Lie-product-formula/10.3792/pja/1195518790.full

However, the result in this paper is not exactly same as that in the book. The problem is the sign. In the paper, Kato has proved

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{e}^{-tL}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(I+\frac{t}{n}L\right)^{-n},\forall t\geqslant 0.
\end{equation}
It seems that it is not straightforward to say the convergence of inverse operators. Is there some theorems to solve this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Kato (like most functional analysts) takes $L$ to be positive-definite, therefore the generator of the semigroup will be $-L$. Kipnis and Landim, on the other hand, denote by $L$ the generator, directly. So, the two approaches are identical, save for a minor difference of notation.

Furthermore, you do not need the full power of the Trotter-Kato formula if you work only with matrices (as opposed to operators in infinite-dimensional Banach spaces).

Going even further, the formula in your post is not the Trotter-Kato formula, so the title is misleading.